# Using 32-bit .NET DLL is 64-bit .NET project

Tags: .net, dll, reverse-engineering

I have 32-bit .NET DLL assembly and I need to use it in 64-bit .NET project.

How it is possible? I can't recompile DLL and I haven't source code.

What is the difference between 32-bit .NET DLL and 64-bit .NET DLL except of PE executable file header?

Maybe that DLL can be modified easily?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a .NET decompiler? They can be very effective: http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx  The chances of getting this to work will depend on why the DLL is marked as 32-bit in the first place - presumably there is a good reason for it.

You certainly cannot use a 32-bit .NET DLL directly from a 64-bit .NET process. You could write a 32-bit application that loads the DLL and responds to requests from the separate 64-bit process.